# What does "Cannot obtain an exclusive lease for ci/pipeline_processing/atomic_processing_service::pipeline_id" mean?

Tags: gitlab

In GitLab one of my engineers is trying to merge a large MR - over 1000 files but it keeps failing.

There is an error in the GitLab logs which is:

*Cannot obtain an exclusive lease for ci/pipeline_processing/atomic_processing_service::pipeline_id*

Does anyone know this means and how I resolve it?

Comment: Having same problem. Have you got a solution?

Comment: @SergeIroshnikov, I had the engineer merge the branch into the target branch locally, build it and run the test.  He confirmed everything was fine so I turned off the pipeline requirements in gitlab and allowed him to merge (we then had other issues with our git - svn hook but that was separate)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced with similar issue and found it on Gitlab - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/331033

According to summary of the issue - "Ignore this error.  This bug issue has been raised to request that the product stop generating this error.". Doesn't look like a solution, actually :(